# Can I use both jcenter() and mavenCentral() to implement Firebase in my app?

Tags: java, android, firebase, gradle

So I am trying to implement Firebase in my app and I have seen in one step that in the guide it says the following ("Make sure that you have the following two repositories"):

```
repositories {
    // Make sure that you have the following two repositories
    google()  // Google's Maven repository

    mavenCentral()  // Maven Central repository

  }
```

In my project I am using jcenter() because I have 2 libraries that are from jcenter() and not from mavenCentral(). So my question is, if in the Firebase's guide it says "make sure to have mavenCentral(), can I use both jcenter() and mavenCentral() to continue having my libraries available at the same time as I am able to integrate Firebase? This is the code that I am thinking to put in build gradle:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    // Make sure that you have the following two repositories
    google()  // Google's Maven repository

    mavenCentral()  // Maven Central repository
    jcenter() //code added by me to the guide's code
  }
  dependencies {
    ...
    // Add the dependency for the Google services Gradle plugin
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.13'

  }
}

allprojects {
  ...
  repositories {
    // Make sure that you have the following two repositories
    google()  // Google's Maven repository

    mavenCentral()  // Maven Central repository
    jcenter() //code added by me to the guide's code

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify both.  The addition of other repositories has no effect on the way Firebase works, as everything for Firebase is hosted out of google.  Just make sure google is always listed first.

Comment: And could I use only jcenter() instead of mavenCentral() or it is stritcly neccesary to use mavenCentral()?

Comment: No, they are not interchangeable at all. https://developer.android.com/studio/build/jcenter-migration

Comment: Okay, so they are not interchangeable but they can work together, I mean, if I use google() mavenCentral() and jcenter() together as the code I have posted before, there won´t be any problem, right? The problem appears if they interchange, right? Also is it important if jcenter is under mavenCentral or do they have to follow any order as google() should be first?

Comment: I have tried it using jcenter() only and eliminating mavenCentral() from the code and it is linking okay with Firebase. Why? If in the guide it is said to add mavenCentral()?

Comment: These are each just maven repositories for dependencies.  That's all.  They tell gradle where to look for them.  You add them when you need a dependency that you know is hosted there, or not if you don't.  Gradle checks them in the order they are listed.  Some repositories may contain some of the same deps.  I think you might want to spend some time learning about how maven works in general, and why jcenter was considered problematic.

Comment: Stevson yes, but I thought that the reason why in the Firebase implementation guide "mavenCentral()" is said to add it to the build.gradle code was because the dependencies of Firebase were only in mavenCentral() not in jcenter(), so I don´t understand why it is working fine with jcenter() if jcenter is not in the guide, but mavenCentral it is and I have not included mavenCentral, only jcenter...

Comment: The Firebase dependencies are in google, not mavenCentral. Google changed that years ago, and only newer versions are available in the google repo.  Dependencies that are not created by Google come from other places.

Comment: so, it does´t matter if I use jcenter() or mavenCentral() then ? So why did you told me that they I could not use jcenter() instead of mavenCentral() if it will work also only using jcenter instead of mavenCentral...? I think I have not understood you well..

Comment: I didn't say that.  I said they are not interchangeable (they are not the same thing).  Just use the one(s) that you need.  They won't conflict with each other.  Read that link I provided as well about jcenter's deprecation.  To go back to your original question: "Can I use both jcenter() and mavenCentral() to implement Firebase in my app?" The answer is yes, you can.

Comment: thanks, sorry for the misunderstood. But the very last question please. So if Firebase is using google() repository, if my app was working fine with jcenter(), can I use only jcenter and google repositories? What would be the difference between that and using the three google(), mavenCentral() and jcenter() repositories instead of only using the two google() and jcenter() repositories? Which way is better? Thanks, please I need an anwser for these existential doubts, I know I am a little heavy but after this awnsers I will know what I wanted from the begining :)

Comment: If you want to know if something works, just try it.  There is no "better", there is just "working".  If something doesn't work, then post a new question explaining what's gone wrong.  You won't get advice without explaining what all your dependencies and requirements are that are off the norm.  The only thing that's recommended is to list google first, which prevents spoofing of google deps.  Stack Overflow does not take questions for opinion (it deals only with observable facts), so if you want to see what other people think about something, post to Reddit or some other discussion forum.